# using setinterval method in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an requirement to fire an method every 25 minutes. so for that I am using

```
  var myVar = setInterval(function () { myTimer() }, 60000);
```

So, I am curious to know the limit I can pass to this method. Some Blogs say Infinity. But how can it be possible  because it is upto the type of data we declare and I even not know what type does setinterval take. Usually a java script has not an int or string or something. It just have this.

```
var dd=66666
```

so, coming back to my question, if I have to call a function after every 25 minutes, then I will have to change the above line as::

```
var myVar = setInterval(function () { myTimer() }, 1500000);
```

So, passing such a big amount can actually create a problem in executing the functionality?
Please guide

Comment: Nope. It will be called for every 25minutes

Comment: for readability point of view, i suggest use it like `var timer = new Number(25);` and then `timer * 60 * 1000` in `setTimeout` block;